# PHP PayFlow Pro - User Authentication Failed

Tags: php, authentication, paypal, payflowpro

I've tried every API out there for PHP, even including the sample that paypal provided here:
https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/618

The problem is that I set user, vendor, partner, password as described. User is under merchants manage users(I've tried both users), vendor is my merchant login, password is my merchant password, and partner is paypal. I've tried paypal test cards listed on their site, and my cards for live mode.

In every API I've tried I get the same reply (no matter if I go to test mode or live mode): User authentication failed: Vantiv

What does Vantiv stand for? It's not my username or vendor btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vantiv is the processor on the account.

Getting 'User authentication failed: Vantiv' usually means that the account is not setup correctly with the right processor information.
Reach out to PayPal payflow support team to verify the processor information on the paypal manager account.

Comment: You were right - they needed to turn processor live on their side. Thank you.